# While triggering MAP/Reduce script from Restlet getting Insufficient Permission

Tags: netsuite

When i was calling MAP/REDUCE script from RESTlet by using Task module i am getting the below issue, Configuration wise in Sandbox it seems to be good. But i am not able to triggering the MAP/REDUCE script. Can any body please help on this please..

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION","message":"You do not have privileges to perform this operation","stack":["submit(N/task)","doPost(/SuiteBundles/Bundle 10009/Solarwind_Import_Trsansaction_RESTlet.js:122)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION","details":"You do not have privileges to perform this operation","userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["submit(N/task)","doPost(/SuiteBundles/Bundle 10009/Solarwind_Import_Trsansaction_RESTlet.js:122)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false}
```

Code is :

```
var mrTask = task.create({
    taskType : task.TaskType.MAP_REDUCE
});

mrTask.scriptId = 'customscript_sw_jsondata_mapreduce';
mrTask.deploymentId = 'customdeploy_sw_jsondata_mapreduce';
mrTask.params = 
{
    custscript_sw_jsondata_mapreduce_para : requestBody
};

mrTask.submit();
```

Thanks,
Ganapathi

Comment: Can any one please update please

Comment: Any Update please

Comment: "You do not have privileges to perform this operation" should be a bit of a clue.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, but in order to run a Map/Reduce task you need to have View on SuiteScripts and Full on SuiteScript Scheduling. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Insufficient Permissions is likely due to the context your restlet / map reduce are running in. If they aren't set to 'administrator' then whatever role you have running the scripts likely doesn't have the correct permissions. Test by switching to administrator for both to confirm its a role issue then you'll have to analyze what operations you are performing and what permissions you require.

Answer (score 0):

Actually both @luke and @Graham answers are correct.

In order to submit a task (in 2.0) you need to set the script to run with admin role and the user who call it need a suiteScript and suitescript scheduling permission role.